# Compile for architecture x86_64 in Mac Mini m1

Tags: php, xampp, intl

I want to compile the PHP library intl.so for use in an XAMPP installation on a Mac Mini M1.

I followed the following steps:

- Install Xcode
- Install Autoconf
- Download the same version of PHP I'm using in XAMPP
- Build intl.so (configure, make, make install)

I added the line extension="intl.so" to php.ini and restarted XAMPP.

But I got this error:

*PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl.so' (tried: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/intl.so (dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/intl. so, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902/intl.so' (**mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')**)*

I understand that I need to compile intl.so on x86_64 architecture so that it can work with XAMPP, but I don't know how to do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet, sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was fixed using the following lines in the terminal:

```
sudo pecl uninstall xdebug
arch -x86_64 sudo pecl install xdebug
```

The first line uninstalls the arm version and the second installs the -x86 one.
It works for me so far, I would guess that the x86 is emulated in this case because the M1 is an arm processor.